# Накапливаются ли полученные данные в сокете?

Tags: winapi, windows-7, winsock, c++

Накапливаются ли где-то данные до вызова `recv()`? То есть если это сервер и после успешной установки соединения клиент шлет ему данные, но сервер не сразу вызывает `recv()`, а с определенной задержкой, то какие данные получит в итоге буфер, указанный в аргументах `recv()`?
Последовательно все данные получит? Или только те, которые в момент запуска `recv()` пришли? Если все, значит есть какой-то буфер в операционной системе? Тогда какой его размер и как долго там хранятся данные ожидая вызова `recv()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@xinakapu](/users/22460/xinakapu), уточните, Вы говорите о tcp (SOCK_STREAM) или udp (SOCK_DGRAM).

В любом случает первые пришедшие хранятся. В случае tcp все "склеивается" в один поток. При заполнении системного буфера (для простоты назовем эту структуру ядра так) прием прекращается (отправитель тормозится).

Для udp пришедшие данные хранятся в виде полученных "пакетов" (datagram) c соблюдением границ. Не помещающиеся в буфер отбрасываются без уведомления отправителя (и получателя). При `recv()` читается один пакет за один  вызов (первые байты, помещающиеся в буфер recv).

Comment: > прием прекращается (отправитель
> тормозится).
то что отправитель хочет отправить клиенту, будет накапливаться уже в его буфере, если клиент не успевает принимать пакеты?

Comment: Да. 

Сначала в буфере, потом процесс будет приостановлен на очередном вызове `send()/write()` до тех пор, пока обмен не станет вновь доступным.

Answer (score 2):

Данные склеиваются. Принимающая сторона получит всё одним куском. Максимальный размер этого куска не может превышать размер буфера сокета.